# Comparing the eigen values of $A+B$ and $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with entries from $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that,

1. The diagonal entries of $A$ are $0$
2. The first $p$ entries of the $(n-1)^{th}$ row (column) of $A$ are $-1$ and,
3. The first $p$ entries of the $n^{th}$ row (column) of $A$ are $0$

Let $B$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix such that,

1. $B$ has the block form $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0& B_{12}\\ B_{12}^T&\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$ where $B_{12}$ is an $(n-2)\times 2$ matrix
2. The first $p$ entries of the $(n-1)^{th}$ row (column) of $B$ are $1$ and,
3. The first $p$ entries of the $n^{th}$ row (column) of $B$ are $-1$
4. All other entries of $B$ are 0.

> I am trying to compare the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A+B$ for $p$ varying from $1$ to $n-2$.
>
> **Can we prove in general that $\lambda_k(A+B)\leq\lambda_k(A)$?** (here $\lambda_k$ is the $k^{th}$ largest eigenvalue of the given matrix)

I have tried this for a few examples and it seems to be correct.

Since it is easy to compute the eigenvalues of $B$, I attempted a proof using Weyl's inequalities:
For Hermetian matrices  $A$ and $B$, $\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_n(B)\leq\lambda_k(A+B)\leq\lambda_k(A)+\lambda_1(B)$.
However, this didn't get me anywhere.

Is there a better way to approach the problem? Or maybe what I have claimed is false?

***Context:** I came across such matrices while studying signed adjacency matrices of graphs.*

Comment: Since $B_{12}$ is $(n-2)\times2$, each of its rows has only two entries. But the second and third conditions for $B_{12}$ imply that every row of $B_{12}$ has at least $p$ entries. Therefore $p\le2$. Do you really mean this?

Comment: The second and third condition are for $B$ not $B_{12}$. So the second condition actually talks about the first column of $B_{12}$ and the third condition talks about the second column of $B_{12}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't true. Consider $p=1$,
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
0&0&-1&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&1\\
\hline
-1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
\end{array}\right],
\ B=\left[\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
0&0&1&-1\\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
\hline
1&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right],
\ A+B=\left[\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
0&0&0&-1\\
\hline
0&0&0&1\\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,1,-1,-1$ while the eigenvalues of $A+B$ are $\sqrt{2},0,0,-\sqrt{2}$. Therefore $\lambda_3(A+B)=0>-1=\lambda_3(A)$.

Comment: I wanted all remaining entries from $B$ to be $0$. I completely missed writing that. My bad. I'm so sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: @R_D Now what you want to prove is *obviously* false. See the modified counterexample in my answer.

Comment: This obviously answers my question. Thank you. Will it make a difference if we impose the further condition that the upper $(n_2)\times(n-2)$ block of $A$ must be non zero?

Comment: @R_D What is $n_2$?

Comment: That was supposed to be $(n-2)$. But I got my answer my answer by just putting $-1$ in 12 and 21 position in the matrix you gave above. Thank you for all the help.